# Editing file names and saving to new directory in python

Tags: python, regex, path, directory

I would like to edit the file name of several files in a list of folders and export the entire file to a new folder. While I was able to rename the file okay, the **contents** of the file didn't migrate over. I think I wrote my code to just create a new empty file rather than edit the old one and move it over to a new directory. I feel that the fix should be easy, and that I am missing a couple of important lines of code. Below is what I have so far:

*import libraries*

```
import os
import glob
import re
```

*directory*

```
directory = glob.glob('Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test/*.fsa')
```

*The two files in the directory look like this when printed out*

```
Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test\c2_D10.fsa
Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test\c3_E10.fsa

for fn in directory:
    print fn
```

*this script was designed to manipulate the file name and export the manipulated file to a another folder*

```
for fn in directory:
    output_directory = 'Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test2'
    value = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fn))[0]
    matchObj = re.match('(.*)_(.*)', value, re.M|re.I)
    new_fn = fn.replace(str(matchObj.group(0)), str(matchObj.group(2)) + "_" + str(matchObj.group(1)))
    base = os.path.basename(new_fn)
    v = open(os.path.join(output_directory, base), 'wb')
    v.close()
```

My end result is the following:

```
Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test2\D10_c2.fsa
Z:/Stuff/J/extractions/test2\E10_c3.fsa
```

But like I said the files are empty (0 kb) in the output_directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stefan mentioned:

import shutil

and replace:

```
v = open(os.path.join(output_directory, base), 'wb')
v.close()
```

with:

```
shutil.copyfile (fn, os.path.join(output_directory, base))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'am not wrong, you are only opening the file and then you are immediately closing it again?

With out any writing to the file it is surely empty.

Have a look here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

shutil.copyfile(src, dst) ;)

Comment: Thanks Stefan! It was a great clue.